# Help me with datagrid with sortedlist

Tags: c#, wpf, sortedlist

i'm need charge a one sortedlist in datagrid WPF. But i don't know it.
Someone may help me please?

My SortedList is :

```
SortedList<decimal,string> date = new SortedList<decimal,string>();
```

Then i have a datagrid :

```
dataGridPresentacionPrincipal.ItemsSource = date;
```

But i don' know in XAML

I have the next datagrid code:

```
<my:WpfDataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Estilo="StlWpfDataGridAlternatingRows" $Estilo_Header="WpfDataGridColumnHeaderAzul" IsReadOnly="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"~
Margin="12,12,12,360" Name="dataGridPresentacionPrincipal" SelectionChanged="dataGridPresentacionPrincipal_SelectionChanged">
     <my:WpfDataGrid.Columns>
            <mic:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding decimal}" Header="Codigo" SortDirection="Ascending"  Width="25" />
            <mic:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding string}" Header="Descripcion" SortDirection="Ascending"  Width="100" />
     </my:WpfDataGrid.Columns>
</my:WpfDataGrid>
```

Comment: sorry cant understand problem you have. You dont know how to set sortedlist as datagrid itemsource in wpf?

Comment: how show the keys and valuesfrom sortedlist in datagridcolums

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind columns to key and value. Below is sample code:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,35,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="list Key" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="list Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

And test code behind I used:

```
SortedList<decimal, string> list = new SortedList<decimal, string>();
list.Add(1, "1");
list.Add(2, "2");
list.Add(3, "3");
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
```

Comment: <code>   <my:WpfDataGrid.Columns>
                    <mic:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Key,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Codigo" SortDirection="Ascending"  Width="25" />
                    <mic:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value,Mode=OneWay}" Header="Descripcion" SortDirection="Ascending"  Width="100" />
                </my:WpfDataGrid.Columns>

Comment: thanks, this is my solution, I had needed add a Mode = OneWat but whithout it, produce exception

Answer (score 0):

In XAML, you need to create a instance of an object as a resource and use the key of the resource.

Ex.

```
<User.Resources>
<my:SortedList x:Key="MySortedList" />
</User.Resrouces>

.
.
.

<ListBox ItemSource={StaticResource MySortedList}>
```

Comment: Thanks user113496, but the namespace my, where reference? And I work with datagrid, no listbox

Comment: i have a namespace xmlns:t="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"